# How to cite a website where the author/publisher are not readily apparent?

Tags: research

I would like to quote information from [this website.](http://www.napoleonsims.com/battles/battles.htm)

There is a title "Battles:", a website name: "Napoleonsims", but almost nothing else.

How would I find the author/publisher/etc.?

Assuming I cannot find the proper citation information, how would I cite this information?

Comment: Have you tried scrolling down to the bottom of the page and clicking on 'Home'?

Comment: @LeonConrad The Home page only has an email the webmaster link.  There is a better question inside this question, though.  How to cite a website where you cannot find an author/publisher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155116/internal-citations-when-multiple-sources-are-similar/155127#155127

Comment: This question would be better for writers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

To cite a website [according to MLA:](http://www.easybib.com/reference/guide/mla/website)

> Last name, First name. "Article Title." Website Title. Publisher of Website, Day Month Year article was published. Web. Day Month Year article was accessed. < URL >.

On the home page of the site in question there is a link to email the webmaster.  In this case, if you wish to formally cite the author, it would be best to email them and ask them for their proper citation information.

But, if you cannot find the publisher/author, then I believe it is acceptable to merely site the URL. The idea of a citation is to credit the original author.  If that author doesn't sign their work or make their identity readily accessible, you have few options.  Just give as much credit as you can.

If you want to be as formal as possible:

> Author Unavailable, "Article Title." Website Title.  Publisher Unavailable, Day Month Year article published. Web. Day Month Year article was accessed < URL >.

Comment: In my works cited, how should I inform my teacher that I don't have enough information for a works cited?

Comment: @user1380792 I don't know the formal way to do so.  Perhaps:  Author Unavailable.  "Article Title."  Website Title.  Publisher Unavailable. Date article published (if available), Date article accessed (by you), < URL >  I don't think anyone would fault you for this.

Comment: @user1380792 But, I would make certain to email the webmaster in an attempt to get that information.  This way if your teacher questions it, you can show due diligence.  -- also note, there was a formatting error, and I've edited the answer.